# If I close ObjectOuputStream, then do not need to close FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, memory, file-io, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

My code like below.

```
Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap();
aMap.put("A", "a");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("some.txt"));
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.write(aMap);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

I thought I need to close fos, but other says its fine.
Is it really fine to not close FileOutputStream, because I already closed inner OutputStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`No` you dont need to close FileOutputStream.
If you check the code of `close()` you will found that it closes the output stream.

Plz see the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Comment: Actually, it's even stated in the documentation for OutputStream, so this can be expected for any well behaved OutputStream. Quote:Closes this output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You don't need to close it separately. If you close your `oos`, it will internally close `fos` as well. Closing the outer most stream will delegate it all the way down

Answer (score 0):

It's a general rule in Java: if you have several chained/nested streams say
`outStream3(outStream2(outStream1))` (I am writing this just in pseudo-code) you
usually need to close only the outermost stream - i.e. `outStream3` in this case.
Internally when you call close on `outStream3`, it will call close on `outStream2`
which will call close on `outStream1`. There are a few exceptions to this rule, but
this is the general rule you can remember.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this explicitly, it will be done automatically. Take a look at the example from javadoc:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

  oos.writeInt(12345);
  oos.writeObject("Today");
  oos.writeObject(new Date());

  oos.close();
```

The link could be found here: [Class ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)